# Llenar una GridView Entity Framework ASP.Net

Tags: entity-framework, asp, gridview

Como puedo llenar una Gridview con el resultado de una consulta Linq de un modelo EF.

var vQueryTom = (from tom in cargaDocEntities.TOMADOR_REPRESENTANTE
                 select tom);

Comment: Puedes mostrar algo de código?

Comment: ahi puse un ejemplo

Comment: muestras la definición de cargaDocEntities, y cuando la instancias?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo metes en su `DataSource` debería funcionar.

```
var vQueryTom = (from tom in cargaDocEntities.TOMADOR_REPRESENTANTE select tom);

myGv.DataSource = vQueryTom.ToList();
o
myGv.DataSource = vQueryTom;
myGv.DataBind();
```